# Cron Job Not Running?

Tags: cron, crontab, syslog

I have a crontab file that looks like this:

`* * * * * /home/abliskovs/update/update.sh`

However when I check the syslog for evidence that the job has run, there is nothing that might indicate that it ever ran. How can I check if it's running?

`crontab -l` outputs the following:

`* * * * * /home/abliskovs/update/update.sh`

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but it happened to me before so I will ask anyways. Make sure that the cron daemon is actually running! :P Second guess is permissions, make sure it is executable by the user running the cronjob.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Add a >>/tmp/testlog.log to the end of your crontab entry (to redirect
>   output to a file you can investigate or check if it's running,
>   additionally a 2>&1 would include output from the error console)

### Example

> 0 * * * * /home/abliskovs/update/update.sh 2>&1 /tmp/testlog.log

### Also Make Sure the followings :

- **Add cronjobs in a right manner.** if you've used crontab -e within your own account, scripts are run with your user (and thus the
  crontab entry has one field less -- the user to run it, as that is
  known). If you simply copied your above snipped to /etc/cron.d, it
  would fail as you didn't specify a user (or rather as it finds no
  user named "bash").
- **Make sure that the script file is executable, otherwise it will not
  execute it.**
- Reload the cron jobs **sudo service reload**, or restart cron service `sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart`

### How to make a file executable?

Several ways to make your file executable

```
chmod +x /home/abliskovs/update/update.sh 

chmod -R 0755 /home/abliskovs/update/update.sh

chmod a+x /home/abliskovs/update/update.sh
```

Comment: It should be executing every minute, but `/tmp/testlog.log` doesn't exist and `syslog` shows no cron errors, and `pgrep cron` shows it running.  I don't get it

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the script file is executable {chmod 755} otherwise it will not execute it

Comment: To make a file executable, you can also run `chmod +x filename`

Answer (score 0):

The shell script `update.sh` probably contains errors, for example some commands that can not be executed because the command can not be found. In this case it may help to add the path to your command in the PATH variable, or to add it in front of your command directly. It also helps to specify the MAILTO e-Mail address, e-Mails which result from executing Cronjobs are sent to this address

```
PATH=/path/to/your/command:/another/important/path
MAILTO=my_name@my_domain
```

You also may check the local mailbox with `mail` and the syslog file in `/var/log/syslog` for errors. See also this related question why [cronjobs may not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work).

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced same issue and the cause for me was that crontab was not running because it didn't have permission to it. I have changed file and put it in /tmpt/output.log

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/ubuntu/app/artisan cmd:process-order > /tmp/queue.output
```

Let me know if this works for you.