# cron job wont execute

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron, log

I'm trying to execute my cron job with my user (user).

The cron job has no problem installing and the script works if I just execute it. 
It is executable and I have the `bash` flag to indicate it is a bash script.

I created the script by running `crontab -e` logged in as `user`.

For testing purposes I will run this script every min but will eventually change it to 10 mins.

my cronjob should run my script which pings googles server every 10mins and creates a log of it so I can know if my devices ever loses internet connection to track an issue. I have another script that moves the log file every day and then logs it with a date and then this script should create another log file. currently it isn't making a file with this cronjob or updating the file once I run the script.

**my cronjob**

```
*/1 * * * * bash /home/user/ping_scripts/ping-test.sh
```

**my script**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
  exec sudo "$0" "$@"
fi

if [ ! -e /var/log/ping.log ];then
    touch /var/log/ping.log
fi

ping -q -c5 google.com > /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
     echo -e "[$(date)] \t\t google ping successful" >> /var/log/ping.log
else
    echo -e "[$(date)] \t\t google ping failed" >> /var/log/ping.log
fi
```

I have read a few other solutions on, but non had fixed my error.

(I cant describe how my post is different other than it is simply a question, one that I could not find the answer to while going through  [Why crontab scripts are not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working) which is for unique errors to cron and the solution wasn't really unique to cron specifically. it had more to do with my script. To get the answer please simply refer to the checked off answer below.)

Comment: Did you check [Why crontab scripts are not working?](https://askubuntu.com/q/23009/507051) and [Cron Job Not Running?](https://askubuntu.com/q/93313/507051)?

Comment: I never came across why crontab scripts are not working. Ill go over that quickly

Comment: 52 Answers – there has to be something anywhere there. ;)

Comment: ya most likely. there is alot! im just trying to pin point which one may be my error.

Comment: Did you add the script and/or your user to /etc/sudoers so that the script's sudo call works without password?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why crontab scripts are not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working)

Comment: I will try that @PerlDuck no I hadn't.

Comment: @vidarlo I dont think Its really a duplicate of that, there are just a bunch of reasons why It may not work there. Im going through it trying some solutions

Comment: Or have the script run as root's cronjob as you switch to root anyway.

Comment: @PerlDuck running it as root worked!! thank you so much! if you make that the answer I will mark it as the answer

Comment: Good to hear but I'm currently on my mobile and writing answers with that is not particularly a pleasure. ;-)

Comment: ok well I will update the answer. if you update it later Ill up vote it and change to your answer and remove mine. thanks! I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that my user was not a `sudoer`.

This problem can be solved by adding your user to `/etc/sudoers` file or by adding cron job as `root`.

```
sudo su
crontab -e
```

and placing cron job there

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the cronjob as

`* 1 * * * cd /home/user/ping_scripts/ && ./ping-test.sh`

and also make sure that the script is executable