# cron.daily jobs not running

Tags: command-line, email, cron, rkhunter

I created 3 daily cron jobs to run.

Below are the three that are placed in etc/cron.daily

**rkhunter.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
(
rkhunter --versioncheck
rkhunter --update
rkhunter --cronjob --report-warnings-only
) | mail -s 'rkhunter Daily Run (my server)' me@email.com
```

**chkrootkit.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
chkrootkit | mail -s "chkrootkit Daily Run (my server)" me@email.com
```

**logwatch.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
(
logwatch
) | mail -s 'logwatch Daily Log (my server)' me@email.com
```

I replaced me@email.com ofcourse with my email.

If I run this cronjob manually it works fine `./nameoffile.sh`

But it doesn't run daily, what can be the cause or how can I check into this?

Comment: Make sure that the files you created in cron.daily/weekly/hourly/etc are executable
just do a chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/whatever

Comment: IMPORTANT: the Debian-specific changes to cron state that files you place in the cron.daily, etc. folders can only use alphanumeric characters. If you use a dot (.) in the file name, it will specifically exclude it from running. Others (below) have stated this, but it's helpful to state it up here where it's possible to be seen.

Comment: Check whether their are entries in the journal, run: * journalctl --unit=crond That will tell if it was ran and when was it ran.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two possible suspects that usually cause `cron` jobs not being able to run.

The first is permissions problems, that is a user can run the script/command but the cron daemon cannot because the job is in the wrong user's cron jobs. For example the user creates a script or runs a command with elevated privileges i.e using `sudo`, then adds the tested script/command to his list of cron jobs (`crontab`). The result is that the user's cron job will not be able to run since it needs elevated privileges.

- To put a cron job in current user's crontab type `crontab -e`
- To put a cron job in root's crontab type `sudo crontab -e`

The second reason is the paths, in order to be sure that the script will execute, the user must add the full path to the script to be executed in crontab. Another solution would be to expand the root users PATH variable by putting the following line at the top of their crontab file:

```
PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

as the community wiki [mentions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto#Further_Considerations).

You may want to read the [community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)  about cron as it provides further details about the above.

Comment: So do i just put the filename in there?

Comment: It is actually saying that there is no previous cron job for root and you are going to write your first and then it asks you to pick an editor in order to modify the crontab. Just pick one from the menu (1.bin/ed, etc). Pick nano its easy, just pay attention to the instructions.

Comment: So to run once a day at 10PM i would put * 22 * * * test > rkhunter.sh right?

Comment: ah awesome! ill try it right now!

Comment: What is the test>rkhunter.sh for?

Comment: `* 22 * * * /home/sonicboom/somedirectory/yourscript.sh | mail -s "Your script started execution" sonicboom@boom.com`

Comment: Got it! Let me try now!

Comment: So i put this in but it didnt work i didnt get an email or anything, and i also put `PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` to the top `26 4 * * * /etc/cron.daily/rkhunter.sh | mail -s "Your script started execution" email@gmail.com`

Comment: And this is what i saw in my log.


`Aug 27 04:26:01 localhost CRON[2718]: (root) CMD (/etc/cron.daily/rkhunter.sh | mail -s "Your script started execution" email@gmail.com)`

Comment: ah i think it worked now.

Comment: Yeah took a few minutes

Answer (score 105):

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112242/daily-cron-job-not-running/250118#250118?newreg=b6ea241c0dfd4628bcad83e0808944f9) response, the problem lies with the .sh extension. Remove that (so for example rename your file from rkhunter.sh to rkhunter.

To confirm run the following command `run-parts --test /etc/cron.daily`

If your script (rkhunter) is included in the results, all is good. For more information on the run-parts command, read the man pages on it `man run-parts`

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, after various test, I realized that another script file without sh extension is executed

Comment: as @rharriso said in his answer.  it's not so much an issue with ".sh" as an issue with ".".  any file with any extension will be missed.  to quote directly from `man run-parts` "names must consist entirely of ASCII upper- and lower-case letters, ASCII digits, ASCII  underscores,  and ASCII minus-hyphens"

Answer (score 18):

In my system it was because anacron wasn't installed.

```
grep run-parts /etc/crontab

17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

So either install anacron or remove the test -x /usr/sbin/anacron

Comment: +1 Isn't anacron installed by default? I would have expected that. I think that would solve it for me. Thanks.

Comment: Sure enough, it wasn't there on mine.. FFS, I am sure it WAS, as the script was executing a few months ago!: ```dpkg --get-selections | grep cron``` .. <swears>

Comment: Yes I don't know what happened either since it is a package usually installed at startup.

Comment: This is not really correct. `anacron` isn't necessary; the `||` operator in the crontab commands executes `run-parts` when anacron is NOT installed. When `anacron` is installed, it makes those daily/weekly/monthly `run-parts` commands redundant.

Comment: So maybe it was because run-parts didn't work?  In anycase installing anacron fixed it for me.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/437114/11333

Answer (score 17):

I think files with extensions are ignored.

run:

```
 run-parts --test /etc/cron.daily
```

If you don't see your scripts listed, remove the .sh extensions and try again.

Answer (score 9):

Adding to Stef answer, you also should make sure that they have the executable bit:

```
$ ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   268 Jun  1 08:06 00logwatch
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   311 May 22  2012 0anacron
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 15007 Jun  6 14:08 apt
```

You should be able to run them using `chmod +x filename`.

Comment: Which files are these? is it the content of /etc/logrotate.d folder ?

Answer (score 6):

Rename your file to not have the .sh extension

To verify this is the issue, try

```
sudo run-parts --list /etc/cron.daily
```

you will see it's not listed.  So run:

```
mv script.sh script
```

and try listing again.  It should be listed.

Comment: This problems seems to effect any executable that has an extension.  I had a file names "filename.ca" and it also would not list it until I renamed it too "filename"

Answer (score 1):

The default time to execute daily scripts is 06:25 AM. If your machine is off at this time (every day), they don't run.

anacron runs scripts that were missed because the machine was off.

You can configure a different time by editing `/etc/crontab`.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get it run with anacron, I removed anacron from `/etc/crontab` and executed `apt remove --purge anacron` and it works right away.

I do not understand why we need two scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Same situation today here

I did

```
sudo journalctl -u cron -b | grep -i error
```

and found

```
cron[815]: Error: bad hour; while reading /etc/crontab
cron[815]: (*system*) ERROR (Syntax error, this crontab file will be ignored)
```

I discovered that someone (me !!!!) added a line starting with

```
20 38 ...
```

and obviously the 38th hour doesn't exist !

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue solved in these steps

1. Restart cron service to see what happened in logs. `service cron restart`
2. Monitor logs `grep -i cron /var/log/syslog` show

> cron[37426]: (**) ERROR (Missing newline before EOF, this crontab file will be ignored)
> cron[37426]: (CRON) INFO (Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)

Logs show the misbehavior relates to my cron EOF.
After cat it, `cat /etc/cron.d/mycron` prove that this file doesn't have newline at last line.

3. Solution is to append newline to last line.

`echo >> /etc/cron.d/mycron`

---

If open the file with Vim, then save (`:wq`) its also append newline to last line of file.

[force vim not append newline at end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37492670/7508077)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue too. When I ran `run-parts --test /etc/cron.daily` my script showed up in the list, but actually triggering the scripts using `run-parts /etc/cron.daily` brought up an error with my script:

```
run-parts: failed to exec /etc/cron.daily/docker-prune: Exec format error
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/docker-prune exited with return code 1
```

Turns out I'd forgotten to include the shebang (`#!/bin/bash` or whathaveyou) at the top of my script.

Don't just test if your script is included in the list of things to be run - actually run it to make sure it works!