# Cron job not running

Tags: cron

I have created a script

```
#!/bin/bash
 echo "tredor"
```

If I run it using command line, it works, but when I move it to being a cron job, it doesn't.

In `crontab -e` , I entered the following code

```
*/5 * * * *  root ./my_script
```

I expect to see an output "tredor" every 5 minutes but that is no happening. How can I modify my codes to be able to see output?

Comment: By using `crontab -e` and placing root as user in your crontbab will not probably work. Additionally you don't provide the full path to the script, except if you have expanded the path in crontab's file. You can check this [question and it's answers](http://askubuntu.com/q/337204/12218) here for some cron gotchas. Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/337204/12218?

Answer (score 2):

- Use the *full path* to your script in the crontab
- make sure it is *executable*: `sudo chmod +x my_script`
- You got the path to the interpreter wrong in the first line of your script: it should be `#!/bin/bash`
- As steeldriver pointed out, you won't actually see any output
- Since you used 7 columns for your cronjob, I assumed you used a system wide crontab (in the `/etc/cron*` dirs or `/etc/crontab`. Using `crontab -e` edits your *user specific* crontab!

Comment: On using the full path, it is in the root directory so isnt the  availed data enough?

Comment: All good points - you might want to add that the echo will not show up in the terminal anyway, since the standard output from cron jobs doesn't go there (by default, it is mailed to the invoking user iirc - if a suitable mail transfer agent is available). Otherwise output needs to be redirected to a file, either within the script or within the crontab e.g. /path/to/myscript >> /path/to/logfile.

Comment: @steeldriver has hit the main point, I should think.

Comment: I dont understand what is the problem in first line with #!/bin/bash ? I have probably the same problem. I dont see any difference.

Comment: But we could run `notify-send`, right? @steeldriver

Comment: @Minsky sure - provided that cron has a way to access the graphical interface (via the `DISPLAY` environment variable for example)