# jobs not running cron ubuntu20.04

Tags: command-line, bash, cron

My user defined cron job isn't running. I've checked out some answers, [like this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337415/cron-job-not-running), and all these **seem** to be correct:

- Use the full path to your script in the crontab
- make sure it is executable: `sudo chmod +x my_script`
- You got the path to the interpreter wrong in the first line of your script: it should be `#!/bin/bash`

```
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# "sync" is my script, has #!/bin/env bash in first line
 * * * * 1 /home/user1/clones/configs/sync && notify-send "executed sync"
 0 * * * 1 git -C /home/user1/clones/configs add -A && git -C /home/user1/clones/configs/ commit -m "synced"
```

I am aware that the file was reloaded after editing using `crontab -e`. Output from `systemctl status cron`:

```
Feb 20 09:31:01 code cron[631]: (sm) RELOAD (crontabs/user1)
Feb 20 09:32:01 code cron[631]: (sm) RELOAD (crontabs/user1)
```

And the `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` shows only some commands executed by root:

```
Feb 20 09:17:01 code CRON[4600]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 20 09:30:01 code CRON[6806]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this instruction:

```
 * * * * 1
```

That will only run **first day of the week**. Now I just tested with

```
 * * * * *
```

And will end up using

```
 0 * * * *
```

Comment: There is available a plenty of tools like this one: https://crontab.guru/