# Script for checking internet connection and password request

Tags: networking, bash, network-manager, cron

Good morning,

I have a home server running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. It's a desktop connected to my wi-fi connection via an USB adaptor. The issue here is that randomly it gets disconnected from the network and asks again for the password (which is always the same and correctly stored, in fact it's already typed in the dialog that pops up) and I have to manually click or press enter to connect it again.

I have added to my crontab this small script

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! [ "$(ping -c 1 google.com)" ]; then
    service network-manager restart
fi
```

it runs every 5 minutes

```
*/5 * * * * /home/***/keepalive.sh
```

but it does not seem to help and i often find my server disconnected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should do just `if ping -c1 google.com; then`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cron.daily jobs not running](http://askubuntu.com/questions/337204/cron-daily-jobs-not-running)

Comment: I recommend that you look into [dispatcher hooks for NetworkManager](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man8/NetworkManager.8.html) that are executed whenever a network status changes. That would be a lot more elegant than periodic checks.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `service` with the full path to `service` binary i.e. `/usr/sbin/service`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! [ "$(ping -c 1 google.com)" ]; then
    /usr/sbin/service network-manager restart
fi
```

Also put this in `root`'s `crontab` as restarting `network-manager` requires `root` privilege, alternately you can grant yourself password-less `sudo` access for this command only, then you can use `sudo /usr/sbin/service network-manager restart`.