# Bash script not executing from crontab

Tags: bash, scripts, backup, mysql

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -u ******** -p********  --all-databases | gzip > /home/srvlinux01/MySQLBackups/database_$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d).sql.gz
```

which is located in `/home/srvlinux01/MySQLBackups/` as `backup.sh` with the following permissions

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 root       root           134 feb 27 12:48 backup.sh
```

I've set up a cronjob on `sudo crontab -e` to run it every day, at night

```
#Automatic MySQL backup
30 3 * * * sh /home/srvlinux01/MySQLBackups/backup.sh
```

But I get emailed the following error:

```
sh: 0: Can't open /home/srvlinux01/MySQLBackups/backup.sh
```

I've been trying different setups, but can't figure out what is wrong. I can run the script manually and everything goes perfectly, so I guess there is something wrong with my cronjob entry, but can't really understand what. Could you please help me figure it out? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try it using sudo: sudo sh /home/srvlinux01/MySQLBackups/backup.sh

Comment: Do you tried to change owner? If you run this script as normal user, `chown user:user /home/srvlinux01/MySQLBackups/backup.sh` (replace user:user with your username and name of your user group). With that you can normaly run script as regular user. Also, if owner is root, do what @Guru saw, run script with sudo.

Comment: So, now I changed my script owner to srvlinux01 (main user) and moved the cronjob to **crontab -e** instead of **sudo crontab -e**.

Still no luck though, wierdly enough it still can't find the file. If I just copy the command and paste it into the terminal it runs normally and makes the backup!

Comment: Could it be that you need to give your cron a PATH? For instance: `SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin` In your case, try putting: `SHELL=/bin/sh PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/srvlinux01/MySQLBackups/` before your command.

Comment: Or could you try changing the shebang to `#!/bin/sh`?

Comment: Why doesn't your `backup.sh` have execute permissions? Given that it is world readable, removing the x permissions for group and other is pointless as world could just do `cat backup.sh | sh` and achieve the same. Apart from, obviously, being able to simply read the username and password ...

Comment: I've discovered that the server has home encryption enabled (sigh!) so i tried moving the script into a separate directory, but it still doesn't work. So looks like it is not the issue. I've tried changing the shebang but still no luck.

Comment: did you try using `PATH`?

Comment: Brilliant! The PATH trick did the job! Could you just explain what it does so I can use it in the future? Maybe post is as an answer so I can mark it as correct! ;)

Comment: And thanks zwets, changed permissions, must have messed up while trying to make it work.

Comment: Could you try whether simple setting it to `PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin` already does the trick? Now I'm wondering... I moved the comment to an answer.

Comment: Yes, even without the home dir segment it works perfectly!

Comment: Please check this one https://askubuntu.com/a/1223213/297387

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to give your cron a `PATH`. For instance:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

In your case, try putting this *before* your command. Check the community wiki in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work) for more information on why the `PATH` variable is needed. Here is an excerpt; essentially the idea is that cron does not read `/etc/environment`:

> A common "gotcha" is the PATH environment variable being different. Maybe your cron script uses the command `somecommand` found in `/opt/someApp/bin`, which you've added to `PATH` in `/etc/environment`? cron does not read that file, so running `somecommand` from your script will fail when run with cron, but work when run in a terminal. To get around that, just set your own `PATH` variable at the top of the script.

Comment: I am getting this error "sh: 0: Can't open /root/scritps/cron_job.sh", when trying to execute sh file from cronjob like "*/1 * * * * sh /root/scritps/cron_job.sh >> /tmp/cron.output 2>&1".FYI: cron_job.sh doing echo only. any idea what is the issue here ?

Comment: scritps vs scripts?

Comment: See this too - https://askubuntu.com/questions/264607/bash-script-not-executing-from-crontab#comment1987092_264741

Answer (score 9):

```
chmod +x /home/srvlinux01/MySQLBackups/backup.sh
```

try to run your script with full path on commandline:

```
/home/srvlinux01/MySQLBackups/backup.sh
```

if it is not running - there is something wrong (path error)

Make sure this is your crontab

```
crontab -e
```

no sudo :

```
sudo crontab -e
```

is root crontab - and root is not able to find your script ;)

remove "sh" in crontab just write:

```
30 3 * * * /home/srvlinux01/MySQLBackups/backup.sh
```

Comment: Not "sudo crontab -e", but it is "crontab -e" is solution for my issue. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

I can see one mistake in your crontab file configuration. In the below config you are trying to call `backup.sh` as same as in your shell prompt with `sh` prefix which may not work in cron.

```
#Automatic MySQL backup
30 3 * * * sh /home/srvlinux01/MySQLBackups/backup.sh
```

Solution:

1. change the owner as said in comment, if needed.
2. Make it as executable.

   ```
   chmod a+x <filename>
   ```
3. Update your crontab to reflect this. (calling the file directly, shell is used as per shebang line inside the file)

   ```
   #Automatic MySQL backup
   30 3 * * * /home/srvlinux01/MySQLBackups/backup.sh
   ```

I hope this would help.

Comment: `chmod +x`!! I forget to permit my script execution permissions.  thanks for posting, @Naha

Answer (score -6):

You forgot the dot '.' before the execution path.

```
30 3 * * * sh ./home/srvlinux01/MySQLBackups/backup.sh             
              ^
```

Comment: Hi, didn't change much, the error is the same unfortunately.

`sh: 0: Can't open ./home/srvlinux01/MySQLBackups/backup.sh`

Comment: `./` makes a path relative to the current directory, which is not desirable here and will even prevent the script from running unless cron's CWD happens to be `/`. Also, the purpose of `./` before a script or other executable name is when it's in the current directory (instead of searching `PATH`). It's primarily used when running the executable as the command being executed (e.g., `./script`), sometimes necessary (and often recommended) when "sourcing" (e.g., `. ./script`), but never useful when passing it as an argument to the shell (i.e., `sh script` always works as well as `sh ./script`).