# Script wont run via crontab but works fine standalone

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

First post on this forum here :)
I already saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117978/script-doesnt-run-via-crontab-but-works-fine-standalone) on the forum, but it if the crontab starts the script it gives out an error. (It works standalone.)

See [this](http://pastebin.com/pR98PRs0) is my script.
[This](http://pastebin.com/Ljj7hrBQ) is the Log.

And here is my crontab:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /home/steam/arma3/restart.sh >> /home/steam/arma3/logs/checkonserv.log 2>&1
```

The "cannot found error" were fixed, but the execution of the `arma3server` file doesnt work.

Comment: And what error do you get ?

Comment: When i start with the crontab the "arma3server" file wont start.. That is the error ^^. So the same problem i saw on the forum. What i did wrong there??

Comment: So it's line 62 ? I will guess that you are not in the correct directory. When running from crontab, you are not automatically in your homedir.

Comment: Well then how would my start line need to look like?

Comment: i tested it with ./home/steam/arma3/arma3server but it gives out /home/steam/arma3/restart.sh: 42: /home/steam/arma3/restart.sh: cannot open =: No such file
/home/steam/arma3/restart.sh: 42: /home/steam/arma3/restart.sh: 5: not found                     and if i start it via console / ssh, it just starts like normal (changed it back again to ./arma3server)

Comment: I'm not sure how line 41 or 42 can lead to that error message. Could you please run the script with the `-x` option (e. g. with `set -x` somewhere near the beginning of the script) and [edit] your question to include the new program output? Also, just to be sure, could you please add a she-bang with an explicit shell interpreter at the beginning of the script file (i. e. `#!/bin/bash`)? The script contains some Bash-isms that (Da)sh doesn't understand and mistakes for other stuff.

Comment: after i added set -x to line 2 and in the first line #!/bin/bash it gave me all the commands in the file out.

Comment: THen we need to see that output, please.

Comment: … and did the program do what you wanted? The listing of all encountered commands as the shell understands them is just a way to help understand what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Very often a script such as this experiences a `bash` vs. `sh` invocation issue. In short, `crontab` defaults to what is explicit in the file as:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
```

while your shell is likely running a `bash` invocation.

I would recommend:

1. Adding a `#!/bin/bash` to the top of your script (if that is the SHELL of choice)
2. Explicitly adding the `/bin/bash` to the crontab line such that:

   `* * * * * /bin/bash /home/steam/arma3/restart.sh >> /home/steam/arma3/logs/crontabcheck 2>&`

If errors persist, please provide an update.

Comment: I updated my post, did not work @ all

Comment: We'll need to see the new output after the changing and using set -x as recommended.

Comment: The Output did not change... I tried to set +x on the first line and on the second line: http://pastebin.com/BJuJBNCH

Comment: A bit hard to help in this fragmented way.  First, move `#!/bin/bash` to the top of the script. Second, recommend install https://asciinema.org/ and record your terminal output so we can see it by executing the script in a terminal.

Comment: http://89.163.206.189/crontab/   First file shows the execution and second file shows the restart script

Comment: Parsing those Unicode uploads isn't convenient. One thing I did notice was there may be a problem with your radix calls. You use `if (( 5 <= 10#$H && 10#$H < 9 ))` . Try assign that to a variable outside the `if` like `(( curRDX=(10#$H) ))` then check with `if (( curRDX >= 5 && curRDX < 9 ))`

Comment: This part is working ALL things are working, but the execution wont work:

Comment: This: ./arma3server -par=arma3server_startup_parameters.txt > $logdir/$armalog1 2> $logdir/$armalog2 &

Comment: [sic] "This part is working ALL things are working, but the execution wont work" - not at all helpful. If you are so convinced that your problem lies solely at that line, then your problem is not with your script but with your `arma3server` element.

Comment: The Problem is that the execution of the arma3server element is starting just like normal when i execute the script by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i found a workaround about this:

- Put your script in an infinite Loop
- Wait for 1 min @ the end in the script (sleep 1m)
- Execute the script with screen

Answer (score 0):

Never assume that cron will work the same as running something manually. If you ever expect to run your script in cron, make sure your script sets up it's environment exactly as needed, and uses full paths to the commands you want to run.