# Executing a bash script and call python script via crontab

Tags: bash, python, cron, root, mta

I have exactly the same problem : https://askubuntu.com/a/117989/1012849

What i don't understand it's how to specify path of SHELL=/bin/sh
Because i can't move my script from :

```
/home/ubuntu/folder/monitoring.sh
```

do I have to specify the path on my script or on the crontab? and how can I retrieve the path?

there's the content of my crontab :

```
*/1 7-19 * * * /home/ubuntu/folder/monitoring.sh
```

Content of monitoring.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

touch testcronsh.txt
python monitoring.py
```

Actually when i try to execute my script via crontab i have that error :

```
/bin/sh: 1: root: not found
```

Comment: Check your /var/log/syslog. Error messages will show up there.

Comment: Shouldn't the "shebang" at first line be `#!/bin/bash` ?  That is, without the space between ! and /.

Comment: nop i made a miss copy

Comment: is /home/ubuntu/folder/monitoring.sh executable?
chmod ugo+x /home/ubuntu/folder/monitoring.sh

Comment: Yes i made a chmod 777 on this file
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu 528 Nov  6 13:25 /home/ubuntu/folder/monitoring.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okai I have found the solution.

First thing to know i'm a beginner in linux env.

So i have created a monitoring.sh script with chmod 770. this file call an other file named monitoring.py who got chmod 770.

Than i add the monitoring.sh on my crontab.

What i didn't know it's the crontab user isn't the same

**So the call of my python script on my .sh script must have the full path**

monitoring.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

touch testcronsh.txt
python /home/ubuntu/folder/monitoring.py
```

Comment: `chmod 777`??? You want to destroy your OS -> **never** give `777` permissions, `770` could be a good alternative

Comment: thanks i will do that ! as i said i'm a begginer on linux env.