# Why doesn't duply work when set as a cron job?

Tags: command-line, bash, cron, duplicity

I have a problem with a cron job which starts but doesn't complete. Running the command manually works fine. I already read the [page about cron issues and solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work) here on AskUbuntu, tried the proposed solutions but didn't find an answer working in my case.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

```
$ crontab -e

SHELL=/bin/bash # otherwise it would be /bin/sh
59 16 * * * /bin/duply calendar backup > /tmp/duply.log
```

Btw, the cron file ends with an empty line, as someone pointed out.

Once the job has "finished"...:

```
$ cat /tmp/duply.log 
Start duply v1.5.7, time is 2012-06-22 16:59:01.
```

Instead, running manually the script it works correctly and gives this output:

```
Start duply v1.5.7, time is 2012-06-22 17:06:39.

[cut]
... here is a long output generated by duply.
... and yes, files have been backed up.
[cut]

--- Finished state OK at 17:06:42.581 - Runtime 00:00:03.170 ---
```

I also tried to restart the cron daemon (`sudo service cron restart`) but nothing changed.

Do you have any suggestion to fix the issue?

Comment: use the error output  `/bin/duply calendar backup > /tmp/duply.log >> /tmp/duply.error.log` and post to see the something error

Comment: now `/tmp/duply.log` is empty, while `/tmp/duply.error.log` contains: `Start duply v1.5.7, time is 2012-06-22 18:02:01.`

Comment: so sorry, this is no the syntax for output error! , is `/bin/duply calendar backup > /tmp/duply.log 2> /tmp/duply.error.log` ,maybe in file contains `duply.error.log`  some information of crash depends of `duply`

Comment: Thanks Andrés, fixed. The error file said: `duplicity missing. installed und available in path?`. So I added to the cron file the same PATH value I have in shell session and the issue disappeared. I didn't think it was required to add PATH to the crontab file because PATH during the cron job is `/usr/bin:/bin`, and duply resides in `/bin`.

Comment: Now the crontab file starts with: `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`. PS: would you mind to add your investigation approach to the wiki page I pointed out in my question, and maybe convert your comment to an answer here? I'd like to upvote for your help.

Comment: here o in the other question ?

Comment: I would say this is a trick that in the other question (wiki page) fits better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, based on the comments, follows the answer to my own question.

**Error log**

A useful (essential) first step was to get an error log.

The syntax to obtain one is:

```
/bin/duply calendar backup > /tmp/duply.log 2> /tmp/duply.error.log
```

**Cause**

Luckily the log files pointed out why:

> duplicity missing. installed und available in path?

So I added to the cron file the same `PATH` value I have in shell session and the issue disappeared. I didn't think it was required to add `PATH` to the crontab file because `PATH` during the cron job is `/usr/bin:/bin`, and duply resides in `/bin`.

Now the crontab file starts with:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin‌​:/bin:/usr/games
```