# "(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)" error in the syslog

Tags: cron

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS an a number of servers.

I have not added any cron jobs or edited my crontab on those servers, however, at around the same time for each machine, I get a 75% CPU spike and the following info in my syslog at the time of the spike:

```
CRON[8380]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

I have mono-complete installed and am running a service stack webserver.

What is the best way for me to stop this from happening?  I would like to be able to remove the CPU spike.

Comment: Every day at 6:25? Those are scripts from /etc/cron.daily/. I have only one trying to send mail: popularity-contest. Look though your  scripts and see which script is trying to send mail? That should narrow it down. Then 'chmod 0644 /etc/cron.daily/script-name' to prevent execution.

Comment: For me this message relates to permission issues. So cron not run in specific time. The cron user doesn't have sufficient permissions to write logs on specific location. Change the ownership of directory solve the problem and now job can run at scheduled time.

Comment: Running `ps aux | grep {process_name}` help to find out script not run by crontab.

Answer (score 263, accepted):

Linux uses mail for sending notifications to the user. Most Linux distributions have a mail service including an MTA (Mail Transfer Agent) installed. Ubuntu doesn't though.

You can install a mail service, postfix for example, to solve this problem.

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

Or you can ignore it. I don't think the inability of cron to send messages has anything to do with the CPU spike (that's linked to the underlying job that cron is running). It might be safest to install an MTA and then read through the messages (`mutt` is a good system mail reader).

Comment: Is postfix a good thing to install?  Which MTA is easiest to use?

Comment: postfix is the most widely used mail server for linux, stick to it

Comment: It is worth pointing out that for use with cron (that is if you don't want to actually send email outwards) during the installation procedure you should answer to configure for local use only.

Comment: the only way I know to check mail is `mail` provided by `mailutils` (debian), if there a better way built in to postfix?

Comment: A more simple MTA to use can be msmtp-mta (which is commonly used with msmtp itself).

Comment: Is postfix the one that doesn't actually send emails over the internet but creates a local mailbox that you can check from the command line?  Would be good to mention that.  (Yep it is, used this answer to verify on my other server: https://serverfault.com/a/100743 )

Comment: (mailed 53 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)

Answer (score 131):

This happens because your cron jobs are producing output and then the cron daemon tries to email that output to you (i.e. root). If you don't need that output, the easiest way to solve this is to discard it at the crontab:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and add `>/dev/null 2>&1` to every job:

```
* * * * * yourCommand >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is it doesn't explain the high CPU usage. Cron is clearly trying to be communicative and this is essentially just ignoring the output. I'd be more inclined to handle the output than discard it, just in case there's useful debug info.

Comment: Oli, even though this is an old question, I am experiencing the same exact issue but it is on Raspberry PI. I see bunch of `No MTA installed, discarding output` message in the log and my program eventually stops running on its own. I believe it is because of CPU spike. It looks like all the answer posted for this question seem to ignore that.

Comment: To keep the output, put the command in a script, and pipe stdout and stderr to `logger`. For example, `yourCommand >/dev/null 2>&1 | logger -t mycmd`. This will put the output in syslog for safe keeping, and stop the MTA complaints.

Comment: @rob : Hiding the output is not a fix.

Comment: For people reading @CivMeierFan's comment - don't put the `> /dev/null` in there :) See Michael Hunter's answer for more details.

Comment: Adding a comment to go along with my downvote for etiquette: This is a terrible "solution" to the "problem". Maybe it fixes the erro r message and cpu spike but the mentality of sweeping things under the rug like this is why we can't have nice things.

Answer (score 107):

This is an old question but there is an additional answer that is useful in some circumstances.

Pipe the output of your cron command through `logger` so they end up in the syslog.

It's slightly easier than installing postfix, and it puts this output into syslog alongside your other logs. This command will capture stdout AND stderr so you won't see the `No MTA installed` message and you'll see all your output in the syslog.

Example cron entry:

```
0 3 * * * (cmd1;  cmd2) 2>&1 | logger -t mycmd
```

You can view logs with your tag `mycmd` using:

```
grep 'mycmd' /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: Do pipes work in cron jobs?

Comment: This works perfectly for me. Logs are available via `journalctl`.

Comment: Perfect Answer.

Comment: This answer should be marked as a solution because it exactly solves the question in a modern way with the Syslog service.

Comment: This should be the answer! Simple and extremely effective!

Comment: Lightweight elegant solution using built-in tools. Works perfectly.

Comment: cron sends an email if the scheduled command fails with an exit code other than zero, even if there is no output. This doesn't capture non-zero exit codes, and it suppresses the email that cron would send as the exit code of the first part of the command is thrown away.

Comment: `sudo journalctl -t mycmd` can be used to see the corresponding logs.

Comment: @Flimm: Could `0 3 * * * (cmd || echo "ERROR!") 2>&1 | logger -t mycmd` help?

Answer (score 93):

In my case, the message was hinting at a permissions problem with the bash script, but I couldn't see it until I installed an MTA.

As suggested I ran:

```
sudo aptitude install postfix
```

I chose "Local" during setup and after running the cron job again:

```
sudo tail -f /var/mail/<user>
```

In my case I replaced

```
<user>
```

with "root".

I was then able to see the error output related to permissions.

Comment: Thank you for the extra comment on how to check the mailbox to see errors from the job!

Comment: `<user>` can be replaced with `$USER`

Comment: perhaps ```MAILTO=""``` in crontab file is enough to stop email and redirect stdout and stderr in command : ```* * * * * my_command &>> /var/log/cron.log``` ?

Answer (score 72):

As stated in an earlier answer,
this happens because your cron jobs are producing output,
and then the cron daemon tries to email that output to you. 
If you don’t want to (or can’t) install an MTA,
but you want to see the output,
you can redirect the output of the cron job to a log file. 
Edit your crontab file with

```
crontab -e
```

(use `sudo` if the issue is with root’s crontab)
and add `>> /some/log/file 2>&1`
after every command, like this:

```
0 3 * * * cmd  >> /some/log/file 2>&1
```

(`>> /some/log/file`
sends the standard output to the named file,
appending to any existing content,
and `2>&1` sends the error messages to the same place.)

If there are multiple commands on a line,
separated by `;`, `&`,  `&&`  or `||`,
you should do the above for each command, like this:

```
0 3 * * * cmd1  >> /some/log/file 2>&1;  cmd2  >> /some/log/file 2>&1
```

or group them, like this:

```
0 3 * * * (cmd1;  cmd2)  >> /some/log/file 2>&1
```

If the command line ends with `&`,
insert the redirection after the command but before the `&`. 
If there are commands separated by `|` (a pipeline),
the simple solution is to group them:

```
0 3 * * * (cmd1  |  cmd2)  >> /some/log/file 2>&1
```

but see also the last paragraph, below.

If you want to ignore stdout and capture only stderr,
use `> /dev/null 2>> /some/log/file` instead. 
Put the log file wherever you want — your home directory,
`/var/log`, or even `/tmp` if you’re sure you won’t need to keep it.

Then look at the log file after the job runs.

If you find a mangled mess of interlaced messages,
it may be that the program(s) are writing stdout and stderr concurrently
with poor coordination. 
In that case, try writing them to separate files
with `>> /some/log/file1  2>> /some/log/file2`. 
You may need to do something similar with pipelines:

```
0 3 * * * cmd1  2>> /some/log/filecmd1err  |  cmd2  >> /some/log/filecmd2 2>&1
```

(It’s probably also best to use separate files
for commands separated by `&`.)

Comment: This is the best solution for many cases. No need to email anyone if not desired and no data is lost in the process. `2&>1` pipes the errors as well into the same output file.

Answer (score 48):

In crontab add this as first line:

```
MAILTO=""
```

This will prevent cron from trying to send an e-mail.

Comment: Don't put any comments (`#`) after `MAILTO=""` or it won't work

Comment: Is there a way to set this globally? like in /etc/default/cron

Answer (score 30):

If you don't want to install an MTA (which I currently have no need for) you can pipe the results of the cron job to a log file.

```
sudo crontab -e
```

then with your cron job would look like this.

```
0 3 * * * /cmd/to/run >> /var/log/somelogfile.log
```

then you can just tail the log and see what happened

```
sudo tail -f -n 50 /var/log/somelogfile.log
```

This is what I have been doing on any server that I see that message in syslog

Comment: I've done this, but no logging is added to the file.

Comment: Are you sure that the cron job as been running?

Comment: Yes, the system log shows that it's being started.

Comment: You need '2>&1' on the end of the line to capture output to stderr into the file.

Comment: @MattSmith That doesn't do anything, the file doesn't exist

Answer (score 11):

One side effect of adding `/dev/null 2>&1` to the cron job command, is that it will discard both `STDERR` and `STDOUT` (Standard Error as well as Output). This works fine if you don't want any emails from cron. But if you want your errors to be emailed to you, use `>/dev/null` instead. [Read this blog post for more explanation](http://www.mydigitallife.info/cron-differences-between-devnull-21-and-devnull/).

You'll still need to install an MTA (mail transfer agent) to send the error emails though. Postfix is simple enough to install with: `sudo apt-get install postfix`

Comment: As far as I understood '>/dev/null' will only send them, and '>/dev/null 2>&1' will doscard all errors? What would I have to use to get errors in log but no mails? I now get no mails (as I want it) but the ugly 'no MTA…'

Comment: afaik, there's no way to log the output other than to send it to emails. The closest thing you can do is to set up postfix for local mail delivery (if you run "sudo apt-get install postfix" it prompts you whether you want to set up local delivery. While this looked like a pain initially, it actually works a lot better. Whenever I log in via ssh, I see a new email on the machine if a previous job has failed. I find it more convenient than having to check the log.

Answer (score 5):

You can set `MAILTO=””` variable at the start of your `crontab` file. This will also disable email alert. Edit/Open your cron jobs:

```
$ crontab -e
```

At the top of the file, enter:

```
MAILTO=""
```

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/disable-the-mail-alert-by-crontab-command/

Comment: This - in conjunction with Michael Hunter's answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/967798/72260.

Answer (score 2):

1. At first, install `postfix`, that can resolve the problem

   ```
   sudo apt-get install postfix
   ```
2. If Ubuntu, you can edit the `crontab` file

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/crontab
   ```
3. Attention，edit the top file，not any code in the first line，and enter

   ```
   MAILTO=root // current system user
   ```
4. When `cron` executes any task，you will get an email

   ```
   mail
   ```

Comment: Your answer seems to be good, but I couldn't make sense of all of the instructions. Maybe you can improve it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem using the *Kitematic Docker tools*.
Go to the magento container and click on `exe`.

Then run

```
apt-get update
```

This is if you're trying to get magento run on kitematic. The log will show this error on the virtual machine:

> need update.

Sorry if this got you lost, but that's how it works. You keep getting lost, but just read about it and the pieces will come together one day. Be patient.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem today, but on containers in an isolated network, so no internet... And I was not able to add file redirect on each job since they were automatically deployed...

I found this quick&dirty hack, but it works!

```
# echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nlogger -t fake-sendmail' > /usr/sbin/sendmail
# chmod a+x /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

If it can help someone...

Answer (score 1):

On Debian, exim4-daemon-light works for me:

```
apt install exim4-daemon-light
```

Background information: It was installed on the machine but got replaced when I installed `ssmtp` manually. After uninstalling `ssmtp`, the error occured because the system had no package which provided `mail-transport-agent`.

Answer (score 0):

first off all, install  postfix

`sudo apt-get install postfix`

then add logs to you crontab command :

`0 0 * * * /home/test.sh /var/log/test.log 2>&1`

pay attention to your script requirements, if your script need to run on bash change your command like this.

`0 0 * * * /bin/bash -c "/home/test.sh" > /var/log/test.log 2>&1`

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix` anytime if want reconfigue package