# Running a script everyday using a cronjob

Tags: scripts, cron

I need the exact code that I would use because I'm not able to figure it out. I use `crontab -e` to set up a cron job but when I save it, it never works. I'm also just trying to run a file called `newmail.sh` from the root user.

Comment: Have you find the answer to your question?

Answer (score 10):

If you wanted the task to run every day at 3:17pm, you would use in `/etc/crontab` or files in `/etc/cron.d`:

```
17 15 * * * root newmail.sh
```

This says "run newmail.sh as root every day of the week, every day of the month, every month at 3:17pm."

> minute hour dom month dow user cmd
>
> minute - This controls what minute of the hour the command will run on, and is between '0' and '59'
>
> hour - This controls what hour the command will run on, and is specified in the 24 hour clock, values must be between 0 and 23 (0 is midnight)
>
> dom - This is the Day of Month, that you want the command run on, e.g. to      run a command on the 19th of each month, the dom would be 19.
>
> month This is the month a specified command will run on, it may be specified   numerically (0-12), or as the name of the month (e.g. May)
>
> dow - This is the Day of Week that you want a command to be run on, it can     also be numeric (0-7) or as the name of the day (e.g. sun).
>
> user - This is the user who runs the command.
>
> cmd - This is the command that you want run. This field may contain     multiple words or spaces.

from: http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

Comment: on ubuntu 16 and later the new format is: "m h  dom mon dow   command"

Comment: on Ubuntu 19 the minute is first. Also, it warns you about incorrect time.

Comment: The user crontab edited by `crontab -e` never supported the username field. The quoted text is for `/etc/crontab`.

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Add these lines in end of file

```
*/1 * * * * wget -O /dev/null  project_crone_URL
```

(Run cron per once in  1 minute)

```
0 0 * * * wget -O /dev/null  project_crone_URL
```

(Run cron per once in  24 hours)

save file

Start crontab by this command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cron start
```

Stop crontab by this command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cron stop
```

Restart crontab by this command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `crontab -e` since **Ubuntu 16.0+** will not have the user field, so the correct format is:

```
17 15 * * * newmail.sh
```

This says "run newmail.sh every day of the week, every day of the month, every month at 3:17pm."

Other ways [dm78's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/382739/602729) is correct and contains the exact description of the format.

Also if **something goes wrong** and you have a mail system installed it will send you a message. For more info see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/234884/602729)

If you are interested in **logging** of cronjobs, you can use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/121560/602729).

Comment: It depends on _which_ crontab you edit. The `crontab -e` thingy does not have a user field (as you correctly say) but the file `/etc/crontab` (the socalled _system_ crontab) and the files below `/etc/cron.d` _do_ have a user field.