# Converting MKV to MP4 Using FFMPEG

Tags: bash, scripts, xubuntu, ffmpeg

I'm using the following line to convert

```
for f in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 256k "${f%%mkv}mp4";&& rm "{$f}.mkv"; done
```

i need this to also check sub directories but i keep getting token error or bash error

also it doesn't delete the mkv files when finished converting

once i have the line working correctly how would i then go one step further and make it auto run say once a day to convert any newly added mkv files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 256k "${f%%mkv}mp4";&& rm "{$f}.mkv";` is a syntax error - you cannot have a `&&` after a `;`. It should just be `ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 256k "${f%%mkv}mp4" && rm "{$f}.mkv";`. Then, your `$f` already ends in `.mkv`, so the `rm` command should be just `rm "$f"`.

To recurse into subdirectories, use [`globstar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
shopt -s  globstar
for f in **/*.mkv; do ... done
```

All told:

```
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s  globstar
for f in **/*.mkv
do
  ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 256k "${f%%mkv}mp4" &&
    rm "$f"
done
```

To run it on a schedule, see [Running a script everyday using a cronjob](https://askubuntu.com/q/382718/158442) or [How do I properly install a systemd timer and service?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1083537/158442).

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer I’ve been pulling my hair out so if I want it to run say all sun directories or /storage2/ do I just add that instead of the ** in front of mkv

Comment: So basically all the sub directories under storage2/Series. Have mkv files in

Comment: When I run this it says no mkv file found, it’s not searching sub directory

Comment: @playl01 What exactly did you run? If you want to use it in `/storage2`, either `cd` there before running this, or replace `**/*.mkv` with `/storage2/**/*.mkv`.

Comment: **/*.mkv no suck file directory so the mkv are all in sub directories of storage2

Comment: Hi so within series./ we have sub folders 2 deep when I run the above script it is saying no such file or directy