# restarting custom kiosk service with cronjob

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, cron, services

I have a google chrome kiosk set on top of Ubuntu Server 14.04.3. What I want to do is to restart the kiosk every day at midnight. As a test I set a cronjob to restart the kiosk every minute in order to see that it works properly. The kiosk is running `xorg` and `xsession` in order to have a display. The commands I used for the cronjob:

```
sudo crontab -e

# in the file itself:
* * * * * /usr/sbin/service kiosk restart
```

Unfortunately nothing happens! When I manually run the `sudo service kisok restart` command it shut downs the display server and put it backs on. In the script I haven't included the `sudo` since the cronjob is running as `root`. When I view the logs with `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` I see  that in-fact it runs the command every minute:

```
Sep 20 19:14:01 luah CRON[1272]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/service kiosk restart)
Sep 20 19:14:01 luah CRON[1271]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

And every minute I get the same output.

What I expect to happen that when the chrome kiosk run, every minute it will restart which means it will shutdown and then comeback alive again. At the moment, nothing happens. Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/222512/cron-info-no-mta-installed-discarding-output-error-in-the-syslog to get output from the cron command. then update the question.