# Can't get crontab to repeat command every five minutes

Tags: cron

I'm trying to make crontab run a `sh` script every 5 minutes.

This is my root (`sudo crontab -e`) crontab setup:

```
*/5 * * * * /etc/test.sh
```

and this is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "time:$(date)"
```

EDIT: i've made it work by using the user crontab file (crontab -e) but I still need to run my script with administrative privileges...

Comment: Did you make your script executable?

Comment: Where do you expect the output of the `echo` command to go? The cron process does not run in a terminal (in particular it does not run in the terminal from which you invoked the `crontab` command). If you look in /var/log/syslog you will  probably find a log entry confirming that the job did in fact run (provided the script is executable).

Comment: executable scripts shouldn't be kept in /etc - that folder is for configuration files. /usr/local/bin would be a much better choice.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your script is executable!
If so, it can also be because PATH is not set, have a look at this post and its replies:

[Reasons why crontab does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work)

Also my suggestion would be using cron.d instead of making a mess in crontab file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a notification in a balloon at the upper right of youe screen where all the other notifications show up, try this command:

```
 notify-send "$(date)"
```

Comment: I'm using ubuntu server so it'll not work

Comment: Right you are. I guessed you were the more traditional desktop user.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve the problem the way you wanted to, but it just might git'r'done anyway.

```
PS1="(\$(date +%H:%M) $PS1"
```

That will put the time in hour:minute format into your shell prompt. Hit {Enter} on an empty prompt, get the time. Works just dandy on my servers.