# A shell file containing count but not showing when I try to run from crontab

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I am new in writing shell script i write a script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
PID=$(ps -ef | grep "sh gps.sh" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
if [ -z $PID ]
then
    cd /opt/etrans/cronjobs
    cnt=$(echo "select 'count '||count(*) from schema.table where c_is_processed ='N'" | psql | grep count |awk '{print $2}')
    echo "Out side of if count is $cnt" | cat >> /opt/cronlog/unprocess_data_process.log # for log writing
    if [ $cnt -ge 5000 ]
            then
            echo "Inside manual gps" | cat >> /opt/cronlog/unprocess_data_process.log # for log writing
            sh manual_gps.sh
        else
        echo "Inside gps" | cat >> /opt/cronlog/unprocess_data_process.log # for log writing
                sh gps.sh
        fi
else
 echo "gps Process is Running with PID=$PID"
fi
exit
```

when I run the .sh file manually it runs file and I can see all the counts in my log file but when I run it from crontab it is not printing the counts.

Comment: How did you install the cronjob?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reasons why crontab does not work](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the reason is your `cron` environment. Maybe it does not know where the `psql` command is.

To investigate the problem try to add another script to your `cron`, with this command:

```
#/bin/bash

which psql >> /tmp/investigation
```

Add this script to `cron` so that it will be executed as soon as possible.
I believe in `/tmp/investigation` you will see that shell cannot found `psql` command. To provide shell with `psql` you have to add it to `PATH` variable exactly before command execution.

Also read this [wiki question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work)

Comment: Hi friends
i have solved it by bringing the environment into my class path and source that environment its look like
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PGPORT=5432
export PGDATABASE=database_name