# Script not running in crontab, file not found

Tags: 12.04, bash, scripts, cron

I need your help to run a bash script in crontab. As many other posts in askubuntu I'm facing the problem that a script that is properly running in terminal mode does not run in crontab. The error I get is:

```
/usr/local/rams60/build/fdgrib2/fdgrib2: error while loading shared libraries: libhdf5.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Cron output also shows `TERM environment variable not set.`

but of course libhdf5.so.8 exists:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 ene 20 12:54 /usr/local/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.so.8 -> libhdf5.so.8.0.1
```

I found some posts about similar issues like

[Why crontab scripts are not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work/23438#23438)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064518/shell-script-and-cron-problems?rq=1

Following that posts I set PATH in my script adding both `/usr/local/rams60/build/fdgrib2/` and `/usr/local/hdf5/lib/`

For sure I am missing some simple setting but I can't see where.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Try `sudo ln -s /usr/local/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.so.8 /usr/local/lib`, `sudo ln -s /usr/local/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.so.8 /usr/lib`. That's the general way for adding something inside _PATH_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.so.8 /usr/local/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/local/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.so.8 /usr/lib/
```

That's the general way for adding something inside *PATH*.

Also, for check, use

```
ldd /usr/local/rams60/build/fdgrib2/fdgrib2
```

This command will show what's missing in your libraries.