# Tell me where is mistake in anacron task?

Tags: bash, xubuntu, scripts, cron, anacron

I have tried to make this task for abacron:

```
dm@dm-system:~$ cat /etc/anacrontab 
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron
# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root

# These replace cron's entries
1   5   cron.daily  run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7   10  cron.weekly run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly    15  cron.monthly    run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly
@daily 5 /home/dm/Devel/btsync && notify-send "Btsync loaded (pid `pidof btsync`)" "Link <a href='http://0.0.0.0:8888/gui/'>here</a>."
```

this command well done from my xubuntu terminal

```
/home/dm/Devel/btsync && notify-send "Btsync loaded (pid `pidof btsync`)" "Link <a href='http://0.0.0.0:8888/gui/'>here</a>."
```

but when i started my notebook i saw in /var/syslog:

```
Aug 14 10:49:06 dm-system anacron[904]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2014-08-14
Aug 14 10:49:06 dm-system anacron[904]: Invalid syntax in /etc/anacrontab on line 14 - skipping this line
Aug 14 10:49:06 dm-system cron[841]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Aug 14 10:49:06 dm-system cron[998]: (CRON) STARTUP (fork ok)
Aug 14 10:49:06 dm-system cron[998]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Aug 14 10:49:07 dm-system anacron[904]: Will run job `cron.daily' in 5 min.
Aug 14 10:49:07 dm-system anacron[904]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
Aug 14 10:54:04 dm-system anacron[904]: Job `cron.daily' started
Aug 14 10:54:05 dm-system anacron[2616]: Invalid syntax in /etc/anacrontab on line 14 - skipping this line
Aug 14 10:54:05 dm-system anacron[2616]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2014-08-14
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of `anacrontab` is, according to the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/anacrontab.5.html):

> Job-description lines are of one of these two forms:
>
> ```
>       period  delay  job-identifier  command
>
>       @period_name delay job-identify command
> ```

I'd say you are missing a `job-identifier`. So something like;

```
@daily 5 btsync-job /home/dm/Devel/btsync && notify-send "Btsync loaded (pid `pidof btsync`)" "Link <a href='http://0.0.0.0:8888/gui/'>here</a>."
```

Also, the manpage notes that, as of now, `@period_name` can only be `@monthly`. So instead of `@daily`, one would have to use:

```
1 5 btsync-job /home/dm/Devel/btsync && notify-send "Btsync loaded ...
```

Aside from this, `notify-send` would need the `DISPLAY` variable to be set. 
This is typically `:0`, but you can check using `echo $DISPLAY` in a terminal.
Thus the `anacrontab` entry should look like:

```
DISPLAY=:0
1 5 btsync-job /home/dm/Devel/btsync && notify-send "Btsync loaded ...
```

Comment: options '@daily' not working. work if instead of '@daily' type 1 and job start, but not showing message (in this way and with /usr/bin/notify-send)

Comment: @blackbird- you're right. According to the manpage, "The period_name can only be set to monthly at the present time. "

Comment: ok (command $ anacron -T - helped me give message /etc/anacrontab: Unknown named period on line 14, skipping) but why notify-send wasn't word at all?

Comment: from cron job ' @reboot sleep 300 && /home/dm/Devel/btsync && /usr/bin/notify-send "Btsync loaded (pid `pidof btsync`)" "Link <a href='http://0.0.0.0:8888/gui/'>here</a>." ' doesn't show message too

Comment: @blackbird- did you set the display variable, since notify-send uses the GUI? See http://askubuntu.com/a/92195/158442

Comment: no, i forgot about it. thank you very much - it solved my problem.