# Anacron running running my daily task each hour

Tags: cron, anacron

I wanted to schedule a daily task using anacron. After some reading I added the below line to /etc/anacrontab:

```
@daily  10  price_scrape /home/pawel/Project_Inflation/run.sh >> /home/pawel/Project_Inflation/log/task_log 2>> /home/pawel/Project_Inflation/log/error_log
```

This works (script executes as expected) but is done hourly whilst it should be done once a day. Here is the output of `grep 'cron' /var/log/syslog`:

```
Jun 27 15:02:24 pawel-ubuntu anacron[399]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2019-06-27
Jun 27 15:02:24 pawel-ubuntu anacron[399]: anacron: /etc/anacrontab: Unknown named period on line 14, skipping
Jun 27 15:02:24 pawel-ubuntu anacron[399]: /etc/anacrontab: Unknown named period on line 14, skipping
Jun 27 15:02:24 pawel-ubuntu anacron[399]: Will run job `price_scrape' in 10 min.
Jun 27 15:02:24 pawel-ubuntu anacron[399]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
Jun 27 15:12:24 pawel-ubuntu anacron[399]: Job `price_scrape' started
Jun 27 15:12:53 pawel-ubuntu anacron[399]: Job `price_scrape' terminated
Jun 27 15:12:53 pawel-ubuntu anacron[399]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Jun 27 15:17:01 pawel-ubuntu CRON[721]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 27 16:02:24 pawel-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Jun 27 16:02:24 pawel-ubuntu anacron[2762]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2019-06-27
Jun 27 16:02:24 pawel-ubuntu anacron[2762]: /etc/anacrontab: Unknown named period on line 14, skipping
Jun 27 16:02:24 pawel-ubuntu anacron[2762]: anacron: /etc/anacrontab: Unknown named period on line 14, skipping
Jun 27 16:02:24 pawel-ubuntu anacron[2762]: Will run job `price_scrape' in 10 min.
Jun 27 16:02:24 pawel-ubuntu anacron[2762]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
Jun 27 16:12:24 pawel-ubuntu anacron[2762]: Job `price_scrape' started
Jun 27 16:12:53 pawel-ubuntu anacron[2762]: Job `price_scrape' terminated
```

It seemed to me that anacron is actually ran by cron itself and on system start up, but to my surprise there is an anacron service and associated anacron timer which triggeres every hour. When I stop the service and the timer however the job will not run at all. Any suggestions as to why the daily period is not respected?

Thanks

Comment: @Rinzwind I thought about that, but the actual answer to OP's question is only in a comment there.

Comment: "Also, the manpage notes that, as of now, period_name can only be monthly. So instead of daily, one would have to use:"  did it for me . Had to remove the ATs :X

Comment: @Rinzwind good catch, I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man page for `anacrontab` states

> The period_name can only be set
>          to monthly at the present time.

so your `daily` will not work and is causing the error message `anacron: /etc/anacrontab: Unknown named period on line 14, skipping`

Sourced from comments at [Tell me where is mistake in anacron task?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511337/tell-me-where-is-mistake-in-anacron-task)

Comment: Indeed changing it to 1 works, the job was not re-executed after I started the service again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach for me is to drop an executable script in `/etc/cron.daily/` and you have no more worries.