# Crontab command does not function properly

Tags: 12.04, cron, rsync

I have the following crontab entry to automate copying of my files to separate W/S in the network.  However, it does not copy the files but produce the log file.  here is the file contents

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Rsync - MA Inbound Files"
rsync -rvu /media/hdd2/MA-Inbound /media/miracle/
echo "Completed MA Inbound Files Sync, Starting Tally.ERP 9 Data File Sync"

rsync -rvu /media/hdd2/Tally.ERP9 /media/miracle/
echo "Completd Tally.ERP9 Data File Sync, Starting 2011 Accounts Files Sync"

rsync -rvu /media/hdd2/"2011 Accounts" /media/miracle/
echo "Completd 2011 Accounts Files Sync, Starting 2012 Accounts Files Sync"

rsync -rvu /media/hdd2/"2012 Accounts" /media/miracle/
echo "Completd 2012 Accounts Files Sync, Starting 2012 Files Sync"

rsync -rvu /media/hdd2/"2012 Files" /media/miracle/
echo "Completd 2012 Files Sync, Starting 2013 Accounts Files Sync"

rsync -rvu /media/hdd2/"2013 Accounts" /media/miracle/
echo "Completd 2013 Accounts, Starting Admin Files Sync"

rsync -rvu /media/hdd2/"Admin" /media/miracle/
echo "Completd Admin Files Sync, Starting MA_Staff Data File Sync"

rsync -rvu /media/hdd2/MA_Staff /media/miracle/
echo "Completd MA_Staff Data File Sync, Starting MA-Outbound Data File Sync"

rsync -rvu /media/hdd2/MA_Outbound /media/miracle/
echo "Completd MA-Outbound Data File Sync, Starting Staff Pic Data File Sync"

rsync -rvu /media/hdd2/"Staff Pic" /media/miracle/
echo "Completd Staff Pic Data File Sync, End OF Syn"
```

here is the command which I have put in the crontab file

```
30 22 * * * /Desktop/marsync.sh >AutoRsyncLogfile.txt
```

When I copy these commands individually, it works flawlessly

Hope some one can help me out wit this.....

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You don't state what the log file contains; I assume it's empty.

If that's the case, it looks like your problem is due to the path used in the crontab file:

```
30 22 * * * /Desktop/marsync.sh >AutoRsyncLogfile.txt
```

The `/Desktop` part is probably incorrect; the `Desktop` directory is usually in your home directory (ie, `/home/<username>`), and can be referenced by the `$HOME` environment variable.. If you change this to something like:

```
30 22 * * * $HOME/Desktop/marsync.sh >AutoRsyncLogfile.txt
```

- then this should work. You'll also need to ensure that the `marsync.sh` file is executable:

```
chmod a+x $HOME/Desktop/marsync.sh
```

Also, you might want to capture standard error (in addition to standard output) to your log file. Use `&>` to do this:

```
30 22 * * * $HOME/Desktop/marsync.sh &>AutoRsyncLogfile.txt
```

Comment: 30 22 * * * $HOME/Desktop/marsync.sh &>AutoRsyncLogfile.txt did not work.  I will try few other paths.... I think like u said it could be the path....

Answer (score -1):

You have to call all commands including path : /usr/bin/rsync , or specify path in the script: 
[look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work)

Comment: You'll generally have a standard, minimal PATH - (`/usr/bin:/bin`), which is very likely to contain `rsync` in a default Ubuntu install.