# Network scanning script - cronification issues

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

This is (yet) another query about cron. I have referred to the [guide on this site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work)  before posting here, but I still can't get this script to work. It is designed to suspend the PC when activity on certain network ports stop. The script runs as listed perfectly in a normal shell. I transferred the environment variables to the crontab as listed below.

Apologies if this is an obvious question but I can't seem to figure this out. The guides I have seen suggest putting environment variables in the crontab.

```
# set shell to bash
SHELL=/bin/bash
# copy PATH from bash
PATH=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
# set up gt-netscan variables in here instead of /etc/environment
STDBY_ON=1
STDBY_CT=0
STDBY_LIM=5

01  *   *   *   *   /usr/local/include/gt-netscan
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "STDBY_ON" -eq 1 ]]; then
    packets=0
    interface="eth0" #interface to listen on


    packets=$(timeout 5 sudo tcpdump -c 100 -n -i $interface port 22 | grep -c 192.168.7.4)

    if [[ "$packets" -eq 0 ]]; then
        let "STDBY_CT+=1"
        echo "No packets, loop $STDBY_CT count" >> /var/log/gt-netscan
    else
        let "STDBY_CT=0"
        echo "Loop reset: $packets packets detected" >> /var/log/gt-netscan
        echo $(date) >> /var/log/gt-netscan            
    fi

    if [[ "$STDBY_CT" -gt "$STDBY_LIM" ]]; then
        echo "Suspending, no activity for 20 minutes on $interface." >> /var/log/gt-netscan
        echo $(date) >> /var/log/gt-netscan
        let "STDBY_CT=0"            
        sudo pm-suspend
    fi

fi

exit
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1:  as requested,here's the output from var/log/syslog grepped for the script name (gt-netscan).

```
Jan 31 11:35:15 big-boss kernel: [    9.231242] init: gt-netscan main process (814) terminated with status 2
Jan 31 11:35:19 big-boss kernel: [   13.188657] init: gt-netscan main process (2718) terminated with status 2
```

EDIT 2: output from 'stat /usr/local/include/gt-netscan'

```
File: `/usr/local/include/gt-netscan'
Size: 995           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 664072      Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-01-31 12:01:01.979605807 +0000
Modify: 2015-01-27 23:32:07.027119674 +0000
Change: 2015-01-27 23:32:07.035119674 +0000
Birth: -
```

Comment: are there any errors being listed in syslog, or any output being "mailed" to /var/mail/root?

Comment: Here's the output from /var/log/syslog, grepped for the script.

Comment: What does `stat /usr/local/include/gt-netscan` say?

Comment: Stat output added above

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have no user in cron.

`# m h dom mon dow user command`

`01 * * * * {insert user here} /usr/local/include/gt-netscan`

Comment: There is no need to insert the `username` if you are editing the individual `cron` file i.e. not `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: Yes, this is an individual cron file. There are no issues with permissions as I already changed sudoers file and tested it.