# How to execute a php script using cron?

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to execute a `php` file via cron every 2 minutes, but it's not working. My crontab is:

```
 */2 * * * * usr/bin/php /var/www/test/cron.php
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Leading `/` for the path: `/usr/bin/php`

Comment: */2 * * * *  /usr/bin/php  /var/www/test/cron.php AND  
*/2 * * * *  /usr/bin/php -q  /var/www/test/cron.php both of them not working.

Comment: thank you so much. now it's  working properly . i was wrong @path mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the output of `which php` and use the absolute path for php (in my case `/usr/bin/php5`).

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/test/cron.php
```

or just

```
*/2 * * * * php /var/www/test/cron.php
```

---

*For clarification*, the default `$PATH` for `cron` is

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
```

You can check the `$PATH` with a *test entry* ([Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/23438/367165)):

```
* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output
```

Thus, the file

```
/tmp/env.output
```

is created.

**You'll have to remove the entry `* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output` afterwards.**

Comment: i don't understand. i have to define path inside the crontab? PATH=/opt/someApp/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/b‌​in
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/test/cron.php like this ?

Comment: No, you need `*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/test/cron.php` if your php interpreter can be found here `/usr/bin/php`

Comment: thank you so much. now it's  working properly . i was wrong @path mapping.

Comment: kindly, i am new here and this is my first post so i am not aware of rules in regulation in detail. again thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to put call the script using standard web path, so you don't mingle the users and permissions, e.g. instead of doing:

```
/usr/bin/php <script>
```

rather do:

```
/usr/bin/wget -q http://localhost/test/cron.php
```

Then you need to make sure the script can be called just from localhost (f.e. using Apache2 access policy).

This way the cron script will be always run under the same user as the website which is a good policy to have in place.