# kcron not running commands

Tags: kubuntu, kde, cron

When I add a new command to kcron it seems to work fine. I hit Run Now and it works perfectly. BUT when the task is scheduled it never runs. How do I get kcron to run commands exactly as Konsole can run them?

For example if I run `xdotool key Ctrl+Alt+l`

it works fine from the Konsole and from the Run Now button. BUT it never runs otherwise.

Same for `soffice`

which will open the LibreOffice splash screen.

Gnome-Schedule will run most commands. BUT I want to use KDE native stuff and would love to get kcron running.

I am running kubuntu 14.04.2 fully updated. Have tried on 32 bit and 64 bit machines.

Answer (score 1):

**KCron & Cron**

KDE UserBase KCron: https://userbase.kde.org/KCron

> KCron is a tool for running applications in the background at regular
>   intervals. It's a graphical interface to the Cron command.

Ubuntu Community Cron HowTo: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

> GUI Applications
>
> It is possible to run gui applications via cronjobs. This can be done
>   by telling cron which display to use.
>
> 00 06 * * * env DISPLAY=:0 gui_appname
>
> The env DISPLAY=:0 portion will tell cron to use the current display
>   (desktop) for the program "gui_appname".

**man xdotool**

```
KEYBOARD COMMANDS
       key [options] keystroke [keystroke ...]
           Options:

           --window window
               Send keystrokes to a specific window id. You can use "WINDOW STACK" references like "%1" and "%@"
               here. If there is a window stack, then "%1" is the default, otherwise the current window is used.
```

It needs a window.

More of the KCron and Cron:

- Reasons why crontab does not work: [Reasons why crontab does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work)
- Cron Task Schedular: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?64502-Cron-Task-Schedular
- CRON Issue: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?64386-CRON-Issue

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I have tried that a few times with no luck.  Here is the command in my Task Scheduler:  env DISPLAY=:0 && qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver Lock  Still does not work.  Thanks for additional help.

Answer (score 0):

I have given up on this.  Tried everything imaginable.  Kalarm which is also native to KDE runs great.  It is easy to use and schedule and will run anything I can do in the Konsole.