# Change timings of unattended updates

Tags: cron

I have unattended updates set to run daily on a 14.04 server. It is run by cron.daily at midnight along with other jobs. I would like to change the time that unattended updates runs but not the other cron.daily jobs. I have tried moving /etc/cron.daily/apt somewhere else and running it as a separate cron job but it does not seem to run. It works fine when I move it back under cron.daily. How can I schedule the unattended updates script to run at a different time (1900 daily)?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to move the script to a different location and then set up a cron entry (`crontab -e`) to run your script at your preferred days and time.

Note that the format for `root` and normal users differs slightly. When executing `crontab -e` as root, each crontab line has one additional parameter to specify as which user to run the entry.

Cron logs to `/var/log/syslog`. Check that file for errors: `grep -i cron syslog`.

The most encountered problem with cron is that it executes its entries in a very limited environment, causing a lot of commands to fail because they can't be found. It is possible to extend the PATH variable with the most common paths.

For details about cron see [CronHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) and [Cron Community Wiki](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work)