# Delay startup service

Tags: startup

I want to delay start an service on boot. Ubuntu Server 15.10

I've created the file /startup-tvheadend.sh (chmod +x)

```
#!/bin/bash 
sleep 20 && service tvheadend start;
```

Then in crontab -e

```
@reboot /startup-tvheadend.sh
```

Running the script as sudo works but **not when I reboot** the computer.
I've disabled the default auto start after installation.

```
kidkic@TvHeadEnd:~$ systemctl status tvheadend
● tvheadend.service - (null)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tvheadend)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
```

Comment: Does the service start automatically? [edit] your post to add the output of `systemctl status tvheadend`.

Comment: Could this be a simple case of relative pathnames? In particular, `service` is in `/usr/sbin/` and `start` is in `/sbin` - which IIRC are not in cron's default path

Comment: Shouldn't you also be using `systemctl start tvheadend`?

Comment: Yeay. the_Seppi, that did the trick!

Comment: @the_Seppi you could post that as an answer.

Comment: @steeldriver but cron will execute this script using bash, so bash's path will be used, which contains both `/sbin/` and `/usr/sbin` by default.

Comment: @steeldriver for some time now, `cron` reads `/etc/environment`, which has a default PATH defined including those directories. http://askubuntu.com/a/700126/158442

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using `systemctl status tvheadend`, I guess you should also use systemd's `systemctl` instead of upstart's `service` command to start this service:

```
#!/bin/bash 
sleep 20 && systemctl start tvheadend;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's simpler to add a sleep to the systemd configuration file. For example, to delay the bind9 start, we can edit (On Ubuntu 16.04) */lib/systemd/system/bind9.service* and add a **ExecStartPre** command. (See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files )

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=-/bin/sleep 5
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/bind9
```