# Crontab syntax; Multiple commands

Tags: cron

I would like to get the following chain of commands as a cronjob:

```
* * * * * source activate myenv3 && cd ~/foo/bar && python sssb.py
```

It works in console, but I dont get any output from the cronjob.

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/23438) suggestion, by replacing it with

```
* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output
```

to find out whether env is different. I couldn't find anything relevant besides PATH being different. So then I set up

```
PATH=myPath
* * * * * source activate myenv3 && cd ~/foo/bar && python sssb.py
```

and it still didn't work. Finally I replaced it with

```
PATH=myPath
* * * * * source activate myenv3 && cd ~/foo/bar && python sssb.py
* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output
```

and this time I didn't even get the `env.output` file. Hence I think there's something wrong with my syntax - but it looks exactly like the multi-command suggestions I found online.

What's going on here? If it's not obvious, what can I next to trace out the error?

`PATH=/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv3/bin:~/.conda:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

`out.err`:

```
/bin/sh: 6: /usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv3/bin/activate: [[: not found
/bin/sh: 15: /usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv3/bin/activate: [[: not found
/bin/sh: 17: /usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv3/bin/activate: [[: not found
Only bash and zsh are supported
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Ubuntu, by default, the `cron` daemon runs all the jobs using `sh` (`dash`) shell and `dash` does not have `source` builtin.

You need to use the POSIX way i.e. `.`:

```
* * * * * . activate myenv3 && cd ~/foo/bar && python sssb.py
```

Alternately, you can run the job as an argument to `bash`:

```
* * * * * "$(command -v bash)" -c 'source activate myenv3 && cd ~/foo/bar && python sssb.py'
```

Comment: Now I have a /tmp/env.output file again, but still no output from the main file.

Comment: @FooBar what's the output of `grep SHELL /tmp/env.output`? Also run the first job as `* * * * * ( . activate myenv3 && cd ~/foo/bar && python sssb.py ) >/tmp/out.err 2>&1` and check the contents of `/tmp/out.err`

Comment: It says SHELL=/bin/sh. I'll paste the output of `out.err` and the actual PATH I pasted into the question.

Comment: @FooBar Run the second entry I suggested I.e. the bash one, should work....the problem is you have `[[` in the file, `dash` doesn't support that either..

Comment: That did the trick!

Comment: +1 for your encapsulation using `$(command -v bash) -c ' ... '` -- solves the whole tigaboo w/o getting into the (not so) messy details.

Comment: If working with `crontab` (not sure about `cron`), another solution to this is to simply provide the SHELL and PATH variables at the start of the `crontab` file, [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14694543/3126298). Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @DexterMorgan That would obviously wok but has caveats -- unless you are sure about the values of `PATH` and `SHELL`, you should not do it as these would incur portability and security issues.

Comment: The command -v part of `"$(command -v bash)" -c '...'` is pointless. Just do `bash -c '...'`

Comment: I do not understand why I can not use some variables with `bash -c` syntax. 
I've tried `bash -c "sleep $(($RANDOM%30)) && mycommand.sh"` : either `$RANDOM` variable or `$(())`syntax are not recognized, without any log trace