# cron job for binary not executing

Tags: cron

I've got a binary file I want to execute every minute. I've opened up the cron config file by running `crontab -e` and added the following line:

`* * * * * tutchi -logpath /home/user/path/logs/myfile.log`

This did not work so I tried adding the full path to the binary

`* * * * * /home/user/path/bin/tutchi -logpath /home/user/path/logs/myfile.log`

But still does not work. I know the command I'm running is correct because if I just run `/home/user/path/bin/tutchi -logpath /home/user/path/logs/myfile.log` then everything runs fine. I also know that the cron tasks are working because I created a dummy one that runs every minute and echos something into a log file

I checked the log file and everything seems alright no errors other than my mail server not being set up

```
Oct 24 23:36:51 hairbuddy-notify cron[25522]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Oct 24 23:36:51 hairbuddy-notify cron[25522]: (CRON) INFO (Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)
Oct 24 23:37:01 hairbuddy-notify CRON[25527]: (rodzz) CMD (/home/rodzz/hairbuddy/bin/tutchi -logpath /home/rodzz/hairbuddy/logs/tutchi.log)
Oct 24 23:37:12 hairbuddy-notify CRON[25526]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Oct 24 23:38:01 hairbuddy-notify CRON[25542]: (rodzz) CMD (/home/rodzz/hairbuddy/bin/tutchi -logpath /home/rodzz/hairbuddy/logs/tutchi.log)
Oct 24 23:38:13 hairbuddy-notify CRON[25541]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Oct 24 23:39:01 hairbuddy-notify CRON[26497]: (rodzz) CMD (/home/rodzz/hairbuddy/bin/tutchi -logpath /home/rodzz/hairbuddy/logs/tutchi.log)
Oct 24 23:40:01 hairbuddy-notify CRON[26955]: (rodzz) CMD (/home/rodzz/hairbuddy/bin/tutchi -logpath /home/rodzz/hairbuddy/logs/tutchi.log)
Oct 24 23:41:01 hairbuddy-notify CRON[26970]: (rodzz) CMD (/home/rodzz/hairbuddy/bin/tutchi -logpath /home/rodzz/hairbuddy/logs/tutchi.log)
Oct 24 23:42:01 hairbuddy-notify CRON[26980]: (rodzz) CMD (/home/rodzz/hairbuddy/bin/tutchi -logpath /home/rodzz/hairbuddy/logs/tutchi.log)
Oct 24 23:43:01 hairbuddy-notify CRON[26991]: (rodzz) CMD (/home/rodzz/hairbuddy/bin/tutchi -logpath /home/rodzz/hairbuddy/logs/tutchi.log)
```

Comment: A weird workaround, but try running the file with `bash`.

Comment: `* * * * * bash -c "/home/user/path/bin/tutchi -logpath /home/user/path/logs/myfile.log"`

Comment: @RohittVashishtha Unfortunately did not work

Comment: There are several ways a command run from cron gets a different environment (in the larger sense, not just environment variables.)   Many are listed in http://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work .  The one that has gotten me in the past is cron jobs get no stdin (fd 0 is closed), which will sometimes cause binaries to error out.

Comment: @rfm, I'm almost certain that it isn't closed; it is just connected to /dev/null rather than a terminal.

Comment: @psusi Actually reading the source, it's a pipe end.  The parent cron process will write anything after a % on the crontab line into the pipe. (I never knew that!)

Comment: @rfm, that's a neat hidden feature!

Comment: @psusi can't really call it "hidden", it's right in the crontab(5) man page.