# Running a cron job on the first weekday of the month

Tags: cron

I am trying to run a job on the first weekday of each month with the following crontab entries:

```
00 07 1-3 * * [ "$(date '+\%a')" == "Mon" ] && echo "Its Monday!"
00 07 1 * * [ "$(date '+\%a')" == "Tue" ] && echo "Its Tuesday!"
00 07 1 * * [ "$(date '+\%a')" == "Wed" ] && echo "Its Wednesday!"
00 07 1 * * [ "$(date '+\%a')" == "Thu" ] && echo "Its Thursday!"
00 07 1 * * [ "$(date '+\%a')" == "Fri" ] && echo "Its Friday!"
```

But this morning I got the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: [: Thu: unexpected operator
```

Answer (score 0):

From `man test`:

```
   STRING1 = STRING2
          the strings are equal
```

Note that it is `=`, not `==`. However, this is not the only problem...

```
firas@itsuki ~ % sh
$ [ "$(date '+\%a')" == "Thu" ] && echo "Its Thursday!"
sh: 1: [: \Thu: unexpected operator
$ [ "$(date '+\%a')" = "Thu" ] && echo "Its Thursday!"
$
```

The other problem is that since your `date` string `+\%a` is between *single* quotes, it will be interpreted literally, and so

```
$ date '+\%a'
\Thu
```

which is not what you want. Instead you should remove the unnecessary backslash, and then

```
$ [ "$(date '+%a')" = "Thu" ] && echo "Its Thursday!"
Its Thursday!
```

Comment: Actually, the `\%a` is probably to protect `%` from cron, where `%` indicates that what follows is to be the input for the command. http://askubuntu.com/a/106440/158442

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to do this in a java quartz CronTrigger and ended up on this page. Not sure if this works with regular cron, but quartz supports the notation `0 7 1 1W * ?` for first weekday of the month. I'm writing it down here for future me.

`0 7 1 1W * ?`:

- Seconds `0`
- Minutes `7`
- Hours `1`
- Day-of-month `1W` weekday nearest the first of the month
- Month `*`
- Day-of-Week `?` no specific value

Also see the [javadoc of org.quartz.CronExpression](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/org/quartz/CronExpression.html).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is a mix of syntax and suitable commands in the code you're using, rather than the way the `cron` has been set up. For what you're trying to achieve, the bash code should really utilise an `if` statement, like this:

```
if [[ "$(date '+\%a')" == "\Thu" ]]; then echo "Its Thursday!"; fi
```

(Note the extra set of square brackets, use of semi-colon, and the terminating `fi` entry).

The result of which looks like this:

```
chris@loki:/$ if [[ "$(date '+\%a')" == "\Thu" ]]; then echo "Its Thursday!"; fi
Its Thursday!
```

It's worth noting that in your code, the boolean `&&` isn't suitable, as it's really supposed to be used for stringing conditional statements. For example:

```
if [ $condition1 ] && [ $condition2 ]
```

Hope this is what you were after!

Comment: This is actually wrong.  Shell uses shortcut evaluation, so && is just fine in place of if.  It's questionable however which of the two equivalent versions is more readable.