# No logging output for cron job

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I have the cron job below set up through `crontab -e`. I've tried to go through all the suggestions at [Why crontab scripts are not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working), but nothing has helped. The system is clearly running as shown when running `sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog`. The file `run_extraction.sh` has the shebang at the top and execution rights with `chmod +x`. The log file is being created, but nothing is added to it. More importantly, the python script does not seem to be run as there's no output created from it. The bash script works when run from the command-line.

I've considered setting up environment variables, but given that even the `echo $USER` is not producing logging output, something more fundamental seems to be the issue. Any ideas?

**grep output**

```
Aug  6 15:41:01 scalablegpu3 CRON[13723]: (myuser) CMD (/raid/myuser/database_extraction/run_extraction  >> /raid/myuser/database_extraction/extraction.log)
Aug  6 15:42:01 scalablegpu3 CRON[13730]: (myuser) CMD (/raid/myuser/database_extraction/run_extraction  >> /raid/myuser/database_extraction/extraction.log)
```

**Crontab entry**

```
* * * * * /raid/myuser/database_extraction/run_extraction  >> /raid/myuser/database_extraction/extraction.log
```

**Bash file**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $USER
python database_extraction.py
```

Comment: You need to include the full path to the `.py` file.

Comment: Ah.. good point!

Answer (score 2):

You've probably been looking at it too long.  (Been there, trust me)
The shell script is `run_extraction.sh` but in the crontab entry, you are missing the ".sh".  It should look like:

```
* * * * * /raid/myuser/database_extraction/run_extraction.sh  >> /raid/myuser/database_extraction/extraction.log
```

If you want stderr as well stdout logged, you might want it add the redirect on the end (this will help debug things further):

```
* * * * * /raid/myuser/database_extraction/run_extraction.sh  >> /raid/myuser/database_extraction/extraction.log 2>&1
```

Comment: I initially had the `.sh` part, but one of the suggestions in the linked thread was to remove extensions.

Comment: Pretty sure its just scripts in the cron.d directories that operate that way, in that they can't have  a "." in the filename.  Logging stderr will give you the next error to debug.  Like is the database_extraction.py script being found in the system path?