# Why a working script does not execute as a cron job?

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I wrote a script to backup a database. When I execute it directly, it works. I tried to make it a cron job and while it runs (I checked with `service status cron`) it seems that it silently fails.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting mongo backup"
mkdir /home/ubuntu/backups
docker exec -it mongodb mongodump --archive=/root/mongodump.gz --gzip
docker cp mongodb:/root/mongodump.gz /home/ubuntu/backups/mongodump_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S).gz
echo "Mongo dump complete"
printf "[default]\naccess_key=\nsecret_key=\nsecurity_token=\n" > ~/.s3cfg
s3cmd put /home/ubuntu/backups/* s3://my-backup-bucket/
echo "Copy to S3 complete"
rm /home/ubuntu/backups/* -r
echo "Files cleaned"
```

I used only absolute paths **(EDIT: yeah actually I didn't)**, no environment variable, no un-escaped %. I don't know what I missed.

Comment: You didn't use absolute paths: not a single one of your commands uses an absolute path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible reason is that you don't use absolute paths to the commands and some of your commands are not located in `/usr/bin` or `/bin` that belong to `$PATH` envvar in Cron by default.

You can find out where is located each executable of your commands by the command `which`, for example `which s3cmd`. Then you can put the commands with their absolute paths in your script.

Another approach is to assign new value for `$PATH` in your script or in `crontab`: [Why crontab scripts are not working?](https://askubuntu.com/a/23438/566421)

You can redirect the output of your Cronjob to a file to debug where is the problem. For this purpose modify your the job in this way:

```
* * * * * /path/to/the-script >/path/to/log-file 2>&1
```

In addition I would prefer to use `$HOME` instead of `~` within the scripts.

Comment: You was right about the ~ and the absolute paths. Thank you sir :-)

Comment: I'm glad to help, @Billybobbonnet :)