# My script runs fine when I run it from the terminal but it doesn't work with cron. Why?

Tags: 16.04, icons, cron, paths, gvfs

I'm creating a script to manage my icons and I'm using the command `gvfs-set-attribute` in order to do that. The script works fine when I run it with the terminal but it fails to work when I use `cron`. Here is a simplified version of my problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/home/myUser/bin:/home/myUser/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/home/myUser/.local/share/gvfs-metadata

gvfs-set-attribute -t string /home/myUser/myFolder metadata::custom-icon file:///home/myUser/myImage.png
```

I've used `crontab -e` and settled my script to run every minute `* * * * * /home/myUser/script.bash`. The problem is that this script doesn't work at all when I run it with `cron`.

I've already written the `PATH` on my script as described in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working/205638) other issue and the output of the command `whereis gvfs-set-attribute` is:

```
gvfs-set-attribute: /usr/bin/gvfs-set-attribute /usr/share/man/man1/gvfs-set-attribute.1.gz
```

So, I'm assuming there's nothing wrong with the `PATH` here. I've also tried to run my script directly with the absolute path: `/usr/bin/gvfs-set-attribute`. But any of those things worked... Does anyone have any idea of what's happening and why I can't use the command `gvfs-set-attribute` with `cron`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line to your script (obviously before the call to `gvfs-set-attribute`):

```
export $(cat /proc/$(pgrep gnome-session)/environ | grep -z ^DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS)
```

It picks up the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable from your existing gnome-session. This makes two assumptions though:

1. You are running a gnome-session; and
2. There is only one gnome-session

If there are multiple gnome-sessions (i.e. one each for multiple users) you can change this line to work for a specific user by adding the `-u` option to `pgrep`. For example:

```
export $(cat /proc/$(pgrep gnome-session -u myUser)/environ | grep -z ^DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS)
```

If you are not using gnome - then I think this will work with other desktop environments by replacing `gnome-session` with another value - such as `lxsession` for LXDE.

Comment: That worked!! Thanks... So the problem was that gvfs-set-attribute relies on the environment variable DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS. But how did you figure that out? Did you already know that gvfs uses this environment variable or there's a way to check what variables are being used by a specific command?

Comment: To be honest I got lucky with a couple of Google searches:
- https://translate.google.com.au/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://ubuntu-xp.blogspot.com/2011/02/gvfs-set-attribute-et-cron.html&prev=search
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250276/access-to-users-session-d-bus-from-their-cron-commands

Comment: After upgrading my system to Ubuntu 18.04 this approach doesn't work anymore (it was 16.04 when I asked this question).  I've realized that the file environ is owned by "gdm" and it just has reading permissions for its owner (like if gdm executed "chmod 400 environ"). The consequence is that the cat command doesn't have enough privileges to read the environ file and I trying to add my user to gdm's group doesn't work. Do you know a workaround to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, as a temporary solution I've added the line "export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus" directly on my script. That works well but I don't really know the consequences of using a fixed value there and if this path changes under some circumstances. But as a functional solution that's fine...

Answer (score 1):

`cron` jobs do not run under the X window system, and do not normally access GUI objects.

However, you can cheat.

In a terminal, running under the GUI:

```
xhost +localhost

echo "export DISPLAY=\"$DISPLAY\"" >$HOME/.display
```

And, near the beginning of the `cron` job:

```
source $HOME/.display
```

Read `man xhost`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This approach works fine if I try to run any GUI application with cron. But it still didn't solve my problem... The gvfs-set-attribute is actually a command line tool.