# Command fails in crontab but works in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, cron, htop

I have checked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working) regarding crontab failures.

I am running this command to capture the `htop` command and create a snapshot of it in html format ([htop output to human readable file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30224271/6164712)):

```
/bin/echo q | /usr/bin/htop | /usr/bin/aha --black --line-fix > /tmp/htop.html
```

This command works correctly on terminal and it doesn't depend on any environment variables. When I add this command as a cronjob, it just generates an empty html file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- This file was created with the aha Ansi HTML Adapter. http://ziz.delphigl.com/tool_aha.php -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xml+xhtml; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>stdin</title>
</head>
<body style="color:white; background-color:black">
<pre>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Any reason why it is not able to capture the output via `cron`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`htop` needs the `TERM` variable set to e.g. `xterm` to output any data, so just set this variable for `xterm` in your cron line, e.g.:

```bsh
@hourly echo q|TERM=xterm htop|aha --black --line-fix >/tmp/htop.html
```

If you want to test whether a command *really* doesn’t depend on any environment variables – which often lead to problems with `cron`, see the question you linked –, use `env -i` to “start with an empty environment”:

```
$ env -i htop
Error opening terminal: unknown.
```

Combined with the `diff` of `cron`’s and your terminal’s environment that’s a nice way to test which variables a command needs. `htop` in fact *only* needs `TERM`:

```bsh
env -i TERM=xterm htop
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me that `env -i htop` trick to clean up the environment.