# spark-submit not found in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I have a **cronjob** to run a script at startup, which i created using `crontab -e`

```
@reboot /home/ubuntu/startup.sh > /home/ubuntu/log.log 2>&1
```

My `startup.sh` script contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

...
bash /home/ubuntu/ec2-script.sh
```

and my `ec2-script.sh` contains:

```
spark-submit
```

But i'm getting `spark-submit: command not found`. If I try from terminal, it is working perfectly fine. But when the script runs at **boot up**, it is unable to find `spark-submit` command. I try to put sleep as well, so the spark starts properly, but it doesn't help. It would be great help if someone points out what is wrong or missing.

Comment: Have you tried to use full path for spark-submit ?

Comment: Yeah, It worked with full path. Can I ask why?

Comment: It works with full path, because cron don't set up the environment as you have in terminal / bash. This means, among other things, that PATH isn't set. If it works please accept my answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why crontab scripts are not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use full path for spark-submit.

Cron don't set up the environment as you have in terminal / bash. This means, among other things, that PATH (search path for executables) isn't set.

You can set the environment either in the first lines of crontab, like:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
OTHERVAR=/some/thing
```

or in your script. If you set them in the script you will have to export PATH and other variables you set, to get them passed down when you call other scripts or programs.

Comment: How can we set up the environment using cron?