# Having trouble getting .sh working with crontab

Tags: bash, 18.04, scripts, cron

I've checked this link for suggestions but I can't seem to get a .sh script working. I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux (from Windows).

[Why crontab scripts are not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working)

Here is the dummy .sh I'm testing.

It's called `testing.sh`

```
#! /bin/bash

ls > testing.txt
```

Here is how my crontab looks like:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

* * * * * "/home/name/Desktop/Instragram Scraper/Instagram looter/batch_scripts/testing.sh"

* * * * * "/home/name/Desktop/Instragram Scraper/Instagram looter/batch_scripts/daily_0.sh"

 ****other randoms cron jobs******
```

I've looked at the environmental paths for cron as well as the shell and but it seems they have variables in common so I'm assuming PATH is not a problem?

Here is Crontab's environmental variables (so I tried changing the shell command by adding it to the top of the cron file):

```
HOME=/home/name
LOGNAME=name
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/home/name
```

Here is env from the shell:

```
PATH=/home/name/bin:/home/name/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

SHELL=/bin/bash
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT:

It seems the text files are being created under HOME, so I was looking at the wrong place. However when running a real (not dummy) cron command, the cron command doesn't seem to be running these commands from my .sh script:

"instalooter hashtag "donut" "/media/name/data/" -n 100 -j 2 --new"

basically the instalooter command doesn't seem to be running,

which if I run via the cmd line or if I run the same script via command line,
those commands have no problem being ran.

Is this an variable problem?

Thank you.

Comment: 1. No space after #! 2. Try without spaces in filename 3. Make sure script path is absolutely correct and executable

Comment: You can change the path to "/home/name/Desktop/Instragram\ Scraper/Instagram looter/batch_scripts/testing.sh" after you fixing your path in the test script the file will be created in the home directory of the user running the cron

Comment: @ManulaWaidyanatha Ah, I see. I though it would be created in the directory of the .sh file. I see the text files being created. However, the crontab is not running the non-dummy commands "instalooter hashtag "donut" "/media/name/data/" -n 100 -j 2 --new"

I've updated the OP.

Comment: @Sayaka what is the instalooter path edit your script and give the full path to the command. You can get the full path by `which instalooter`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a clear error message in order to solve this, although this appears to be a PATH variable problem(in such case you might need to concatenate path of your program to crontab `PATH` variable)

To get a clear error message from your command you need to redirect `Standard Error Stream` of the command to `Standard Output Stream` and redirect it to a file's input stream this can be achieved with `2>&1` operator, where the numbers represent file descriptors(wont go into details here).

```
command args > /debug.txt 2>&1
```

After modifying the the script once the crontab executes your script, you can look at debug.txt for error messages.