# cron seems to be set up correctly but doesn't work

Tags: cron

I read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working) post and checked everything, it still doesn't work. I'm trying to set a new wallpaper every few minutes:

- `crontab -e`, then line before empty last line `*/5 * * * * /home/me/.bin/ranbg`
- the script in `/home/me/.bin` has the following

```
    #!/bin/bash
    DISPLAY=:0
    f=$(ls -d /home/me/.bin/mutables/bg/* | shuf -n1)
    feh --bg-max $f
    /home/me/.fehbg
```

That last line isn't actually necessary because the script just has the exact same as the second last line. I could have forbidden the creation of it by adding `--no-fehbg` to the call of feh.

**I think:**

- The ranbg script has `ogu=777` so it shouldn't be because of rights.
- The background is set by the call to feh so it shouldn't be because of a missing DISPLAY, so the DISPLAY=:0 in the script is cosmetics

Comment: alway use full path of binaries in a cron script, for `feh` and `shuf``try with full pathes

Comment: feh and shuf are in the script that is called, not in the cron script

Comment: (changed it anyways)