# Shell script working on terminal but not on cron

Tags: 18.04, python, cron, jupyter

I am using jupyter notebook on virtual environment to extract data using selenium.
I have used a shell script to [run the jupyter notebook on cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49510178/11593389) as recommended.

```
#!/bin/bash

/home/username/environments/venv/bin/jupyter nbconvert \
        --execute \
        --to notebook /home/username/environments/venv/jupyter_scripts/Untitled1.ipynb \
        --output /home/username/environments/venv/jupyter_scripts/Untitled2.ipynb \
```

I am able to run this script on terminal and it is giving the output csv file.
But when I run the same script on cronjob, it’s not giving me the output csv file. Following is the log from cronlog:

```
Jan 28 06:57:01 username cron[23859]: (root) RELOAD (crontabs/root)
Jan 28 06:57:02 username CRON[25475]: (root) CMD (/home/username/environments/project/script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

Which means the shell script is getting executed. Yet I am not getting the output csv file.
Can anyone please help me understand what is the issue here? How can I resolve this issue?

Edit:
Following is the cronjob

```
57 06 * * * /home/username/environments/project/script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Then change the cron cmd as follows to get the log in a separate log file than the cronlog as follows.

```
/home/username/environments/project/script.sh > /home/username/environments/project/script.log 2>&1
```

From script.log I found the following error

```
[NbConvertApp] ERROR | Error while converting '/home/username/environments/venv/jupyter_scripts/Untitled1.ipynb'
```

But when running `./script.sh` I got the following log on terminal

```
username@username:~/environments/project$ ./script.sh
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook /home/username/environments/venv/jupyter_scripts/Untitled1.ipynb to notebook
[NbConvertApp] Executing notebook with kernel: python3
[NbConvertApp] Writing 3543 bytes to /home/username/environments/venv/jupyter_scripts/Untitled2.ipynb
```

And the desired csv output was also created while running the script on terminal.

Comment: Why did you not include the line you added to cron? 75% of the issues with cron relate to NOT using absolute paths or not setting cron up to accepts relative paths.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why crontab scripts are not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working)

Comment: @Melebius I changed the permission for the shell script for it to executable.