# Cron not running bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

Running Ubuntu 19.10

I have reviewed the [wiki on crontab scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working) but I am still unsure why mine is not starting.  The bash script I would like to run is here:

```
#!/bin/bash
now_hour=$(date "+%H")

while ((now_hour < 21))
do
    start_time=$(date "+%d.%m.%Y-%H:%M:%S")
    status=$(ping -q -w 1 -c 1 `ip r | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3` > /dev/null  && echo ok || echo error)

    if [ "$status" == "ok" ]
    then
        timeout 30m vlc -vvv http://10.0.0.113:8000/stream.mjpg --sout="#std{acces=file,mux=ogg,dst=/home/whsrobotics/KestrelCam/Recordings/Kestrel_Box:$start_time.mp4}"
        echo "$start_time,recording_started" | tee -a "/home/whsrobotics/KestrelCam/log.txt"
    else
        echo "$start_time,network_problem" | tee -a "/home/whsrobotics/KestrelCam/log.txt"
        sleep 5m
    fi
    now_hour=$(date "+%H")
done
```

My crontab file is here:

```
# crontab -e
SHELL=/bin/bash

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed

# start the Kestrel Camera recording at 5:00 am every day (will run to at least 9:00 pm)
00 05 * * * /home/whsrobotics/KestrelCam/all_day
```

The script works as intended when manually started in the terminal but not from cron.  I have a suspicion that it may be the PATH but I am not sure how to address that.  Any suggestions here are appreciated.

Comment: Try changing cron line to `00 05 * * *  /bin/bash /home/whsrobotics/KestrelCam/all_day`

Comment: The first thing I would do is *redirect the output/error from the crontab to a log file* - ex. append `>/home/whsrobotics/KestrelCam/cron.log 2>&1` - otherwise we're all guessing

Comment: The cron.log file contains these lines repeatedly: timeout: failed to run command ‘vlc’: No such file or directory
11.04.2020-18:12:01,recording_started

Comment: The second part is the echo command in the script.

Comment: Run `which vlc` and try to add the full path in the output instead of just using `vlc` in your script. Like so `timeout 30m /usr/bin/vlc -vvv http://10.0.0.11.......`

Comment: The suggestion from @Raffa seems to have gotten VLC running but it is creating a new file in the Recordings directory every second.  They are not actually mp4 files but empty text files.

Comment: `while ((now_hour < 21))` should be `while (("$now_hour" < 21))`

Comment: Same result.  When I run script from terminal it works but when it runs from cron it is as if it is running over and over again every second.

Comment: The first line of the log output is "error: unable to open display"

Comment: Probably you are using root crontab which is not advised in this case. Try using your own user crontab ie `crontab -e` no sudo. Or if you must use root crontab, then you need to specify the display before the command, something like this `00 05 * * * env DISPLAY=:0 /home/whsrobotics/KestrelCam/all_day`

Comment: I'm not using sudo crontab.

Comment: @Raffa from the ARITHMETIC EVALUATION section of `man bash`: *Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name without  using  the  parameter expansion syntax.* - so `now_hour` is fine

Comment: Then try to specify a display environment. It can be `:0` or `:0:0` or something else. Run `echo $DISPLAY` to find out.

Comment: @steeldriver I know. But `GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release` is complaining.

Comment: `echo $DISPLAY` returns `:0`

Comment: So add it as in my comment above and see if it works

Comment: Isn't there a way to run vlc in headless mode (`cvlc` maybe?) for these kinds of transcoding applications? that might avoid issues with display settings

Comment: Thank you @Raffa.  The last suggestion to add `env DISPLAY=:0` solved the problem for me.