# Crontab will not perform any tasks

Tags: 20.04, sudo, cron, python3

I have a python file that has to be run with `sudo` elevation every 6 hours.

I created the cronjob using `sudo crontab -e` and then added the entry:

```
0 */6 * * * cd /home/timeflow/backup && sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/timeflow/backup/backup_db.py
```

However, this file is never ran. I have also tried removing `sudo` from `sudo /usr/bin/python3 home/timeflow/backup/backup_db.py`, however this does nothing as well. For clarity:

```
0 */6 * * * cd /home/timeflow/backup && /usr/bin/python3 /home/timeflow/backup/backup_db.py
```

I have no idea why this is not working. I tried to do a smaller job, by creating a random python file in the same repo to no avail. The entry was:

```
* */6 * * * touch /home/timeflow/test.py
```

Comment: Are you really running 14.04, which is now ~3 years past end-of-life? Is your home directory encrypted? Does `/var/log/syslog` show any entries related to these cronjobs? Also try the answers in https://askubuntu.com/q/23009/158442

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard or public support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in *extended* support and supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/   *You didn't specifically mention a release; but you've tagged your release as an off-topic release*

Comment: @muru @guiverc Sorry that was a mis-click. I am running 20.04. `/var/log/syslog` seems to show that the cronjobs are running properly.

Comment: One way to troubleshoot this is to write a script containing three commands: first, echo something "I have started", and then include the `cd` and `python3` commands. Modify the python program to print debugging messages to sysout. Have cron run that script instead, and redirect sysout and syserr to a log file.